# Необходимо чтобы блок разрезал текст по диагонали

Tags: jquery, css3

Хочу сделать анимацию. Пробовал разные способы, но все не выходит.
Любой, например цветом залиты блок должен по диагонали разрезать текст, что находится справа от него.

Буду заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Не очень понятна задача, да и покажи наработки, ИИ.

Comment: Да собственно говоря решил вопрос. Помогла статья http://frontender.info/css-shapes/
+
Добавил анимацию. Если кому потребуется могу описать подробно.

Answer (score 1):

Используй линейный градиент 0, 50%, 50%, 100% по диагонали.